# I want my code to go through the if tests but after the third one it starts the sequence again

Tags: reactjs

The code is supposed to go through the if tests in order and repeat indefinently.

I tried to set up a simple counter that increases after every if test and after the last one it sets the counter back to 1 so that the first if test runs again. The code is meant to loop through the if tests.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import GenerateScramble from './ScrambleGenerator';
import SecondsCounter from './SecondsCounter';


function App() {
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);
 

  var spaceEventCounter = 1;

  document.addEventListener('keydown', (spaceDown) => { 
    if(spaceDown.code === 'Space' && spaceEventCounter === 1){ 

      console.log(spaceEventCounter);
      spaceEventCounter = 2;
    }
  }); 

  document.addEventListener('keyup', (spaceUp) => { 
  if(spaceUp.code === 'Space' && spaceEventCounter === 2){ 
      setIsRunning(true);

      console.log(spaceEventCounter);
      spaceEventCounter = 3;
    }
  }); 

  document.addEventListener('keydown', (spaceDown) => { 
    if(spaceDown.code === 'Space' && spaceEventCounter === 3){ 
      setIsRunning(false);

      console.log(spaceEventCounter);
      spaceEventCounter = 4;
    }
  }); 

  document.addEventListener('keyup', (spaceUp) => { 
    if(spaceUp.code === 'Space' && spaceEventCounter === 4){ 

      console.log(spaceEventCounter);
      spaceEventCounter = 1;
    }
  }); 


  return (
    <>
      <GenerateScramble />
    
      <SecondsCounter isRunning={isRunning} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you `setIsRunning` your `spaceEventCounter` variable will be ***re-initialized*** to `1`.

To prevent this you could make it a state as well

```js
const [spaceEventCounter, setSpaceEventCounter] = useState(1);
```

You also might want to use a `useEffect` to create your eventListeners, currently you're adding new listeners everytime the component re-renders

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.code !== "Space") return;
    if (spaceEventCounter === 1) {
      setSpaceEventCounter(2);
    }
    if (spaceEventCounter === 3) {
      setIsRunning(false);

      console.log(spaceEventCounter);
      setSpaceEventCounter(4);
    }
  };

  const handleKeyUp = (event) => {
    if (event.code !== "Space") return;
    if (spaceEventCounter === 2) {
      setIsRunning(true);

      console.log(spaceEventCounter);
      setSpaceEventCounter(3);
    }
    if (spaceEventCounter === 4) {
      console.log(spaceEventCounter);
      setSpaceEventCounter(1);
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);

  document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);

  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    document.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
  };
}, [spaceEventCounter]);
```